# Nilpotent Operator Minimal Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials, nilpotence

Given a Nilpotent Operator $F: V\rightarrow V$ with index $k$, that being the smallest $k$ such that $F^k = 0$, show the minimal polynomial is $M(t) = t^k$. It's obvious that $M(F) = 0$, but how do I know there is no Polynomial of $deg < k$ that also satisfies the condition?

Comment: What does "index $k$" mean? I suspect you will find the answer there.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks, I edited it in.

Comment: Shouldn't it be clear then? The matrix satisfies $F^k = 0$, so the minimal polynomial divides $t^k$. The only monic polynomials dividing $t^k$ are $1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential point to use is that any annihilating polynomial of the operator $F$ must be a (polynomial) multiple of its minimal polynomial, or equivalently the minimal polynomial must divide any given annihilating polynomial. Since by hypothesis $X^k$ is an annihilating polynomial, the only candidates for a minimal polynomial are its monic divisors, which are $1,X,X^2,\ldots,X^k$. But by what is given, all of them except the last one are *not* annihilating polynomials. It remains as only possibility that $X^k$ must be the minimal polynomial.